# Confusion about two limits..

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I am really confused about this two facts.

1. If $\lim a^{1/n}=1$ then why $\lim a^{1/2^{n}}\ne1$
2. If $\lim n^{1/n}=1$ then why $\lim n!^{1/n}$ tends to $\infty$..

Comment: What makes you think $\lim a^{1/2^n}\not=1$?

Comment: what is the limit? $n \to \infty$ ?

Comment: @BarryCipra ..sorry I misread that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You are wrong. *Both* limits are equal to $1$.
2. What's confusing about this? After all, $(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}):n^{1/n}\leqslant n!^{1/n}$.

Comment: Sorry for first..I misread that..But for second I was confused because $n!$ is  n(n-1)(n-2)...3.2.1 and so taking $1/n$ root of each term and applying limit we will get 1 * 1 *1...*1 n times that should come 1...

Comment: @omkarGirkar By the argument, the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n$ should be $1$ too. After all$$\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n=\overbrace{\left(1+\frac1n\right)\left(1+\frac1n\right)\cdots\left(1+\frac1n\right)}^{n\text{ times}}$$and each $1+\frac1n$ goes to $1$.

Comment: What a point...but what goes wrong in this.?

Comment: @omkarGirkar Each term is closer and closer to $1$ but, on the other hand, you have more and more terms as $n$ goes to $\infty$.